# How to use EJS tags in a JS string

Tags: javascript, tags, ejs

```
<%
   let myString = "this is a string %> with special characters";
   let myOtherString = "this is a string <% with special characters";
   // Do something
%>
```

I need to use these special characters in my JS string <% and/or %>. But EJS template would return errors: Could not find matching close tag for "<%" or SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token while compiling ejs for %>

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply concatenate two strings together:

```js
let myString = "this is a string %" + "> with special characters";
```

or with template literals to make it a bit less ugly:

```js
let startTag = '<' + '%';

let myString = `this is a string ${startTag} with special characters`;
```

For the record, [their documentation](https://ejs.co/) lists options to change the starting/ending tags, which they call delimiters, in case you prefer e.g. `<!` and `!>`. Their documentation also mentions that `<%%` should print `<%` but I personally don't know if this works within a `<% code %>` block.

Comment: @akl Then don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to your question